# Can iOS App Process Location Info while it's not running?

Tags: ios, resources, geolocation

I want to ask about iOS application characteristic/behavior regarding processing location information. My previous wording isn't straightforward and seems to make it look unclear (which is my problem with ESL.) I hope this way I can get

As we know in App Store sometimes an app is tagged with *"This app may use your location even when it isn't open, which can decrease device battery life."*

Is it correct to conclude that iOS really allows an app to be closed (swiped up close from app switcher) and still use location data? or what it meant with "isn't open" is just "is not in foreground?"

Answer (score -2):

Do you want your app to be available on the AppStore? If yes, then the answer is “only if you convince the user to go to settings and allow it”.

Don’t expect help from any decent developers.

Comment: I edited my question with background. No I'm not app developer, I'm just a user for Moves app back then in 2013-2014 and have been used to location tagging app ever since. I did allow the app to Always use my location.

So I guess your answer is yes? from your answer I don't see you deny that iOS technically does not allow app to run in closed state.

I always think of that, I think what makes iOS secure is we can just swipe app close to make sure that particular app does not do anything to our phone. Let alone app is still residing in memory after uninstalled, I'm sure iOS does not allow.

Comment: If you are not a developer then why do you ask about developing?

Comment: Maybe I should refine my question, it's not about developing but more like questioning if an iOS app is possible to do that. Apparently my way to ask was in different style like "if we are to develop an app, can we make this" rather than on point "can iOS apps do this" my bad. So I guess your answer is no? it's not possible for an app to still tracking location with app "swiped up closed?" then as a user keeping multiple app that not often used I can be sure they are not wasting resources. Otherwise I should not keep apps that I rarely use. thankyou.